# Jquery datatables - Dropdown filter for server side processing from INNER JOIN

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

**I have modified serverside processing script with $acolumns and $bcolumns.
This is because i have used 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' for the SQL query and 'To and from date filter' to filter one of the columns for the table. 
For this i have modified both $sWhere and $sQuery.
This is all working brilliantly but i cant populate the filters in the table with the values from the fields.**

Any help/ guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

**Javascript:**

---

```
var $oTable;
var asInitVals = new Array();
var aSelected = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
        var $oTable= $("#example").dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search:"
        },
        "sDom":"lfrtip", // default is lfrtip, where the f is the filter
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSearchable": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sName": "catname", "sTitle": "Division"} ,
            { "sName": "cname", "sTitle": "Course"} ,
            { "sName": "status", "sTitle": "Code"} ,
            { "sName": "mname","sTitle": "Module"} ,
            { "sName": "searchdateadded", "sTitle": "Created"},
            ],
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
            if ( jQuery.inArray(aData.DT_RowId, aSelected) !== -1 ) {
                $(nRow).addClass('row_selected');
            }
        },
        //"sDom": '<"clear"fl>t<"clear"><"bottom"ip><"clear">',
        "iDisplayLength": 20,       
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData, fnCallback) {
               aoData.push( { "name": "min", "value":  $('#min').val() } );
               aoData.push( { "name": "max", "value":  $('#max').val() } );
        }
        }).columnFilter({aoColumns:[
                { type:"select"},
                { type:"select"},
                { type:"select"},
                { type:"select"},
                { type:"select"}
                ]}
            );  


// Implements the jQuery UI Datepicker widget on the date controls
$('#min, #max').daterangepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
     onClose: function(event) {
        $oTable.fnDraw();
    }
    //showOn: 'button', 
    //buttonImage: '../images/calendar.jpg', 
    //buttonImageOnly: true
}).change(function() {
    $oTable.fnDraw();
});        


//Button to clear the filter
$('#clear').click(function(){ 
   $('#min').val('') ;
   $('#max').val('') ;
   $oTable.fnDraw('');
}); 

/* Add event listeners to the two range filtering inputs */
$('#min').keyup( function() { $oTable.fnDraw(); });
$('#min').change( function() { $oTable.fnDraw(); });

/* Add event listeners to the two range filtering inputs */
$('#max').keyup( function() { $oTable.fnDraw(); });
$('#max').change( function() { $oTable.fnDraw(); });


$('input[type=text]').addClass("idleField");  

$('input[type=text]').focus(function() {  
            $(this).removeClass("idleField").addClass("focusField");  
            if (this.value == this.defaultValue){  
            }  
            if(this.value != this.defaultValue){  
                this.select();  
            }  
        });  
$('input[type=text]').focusout(function() {  
            $(this).removeClass("focusField").addClass("idleField");  
});


/* Click event handler */
$('#example tbody tr').live('click', function () {
        var id = this.id;
        var index = jQuery.inArray(id, aSelected);

        if ( index === -1 ) {
            aSelected.push( id );
        } else {
            aSelected.splice( index, 1 );
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
    } );
} );
```

---

**My Serverside processing as follows:**

---

```
<?php
    /*
     * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
     * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine
     * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
     */

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array('catname','cname', 'short', 'mname', 'searchdateadded');
    $bColumns = array('cc.name','c.fullname', 'c.shortname', 'm.name', 'cm.added');

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "id";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "mdl_course_modules";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "user";
    $gaSql['password']   = "password";
    $gaSql['db']         = "db";
    $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */

    /* 
     * MySQL connection
     */
    $gaSql['link'] =  mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) or
        die( 'Could not open connection to server' );

    mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) or 
        die( 'Could not select database '. $gaSql['db'] );


    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }


    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }


    /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "AND (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($bColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $bColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ') ';
    }



    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($bColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = " AND ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $bColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%'";
        }
    }


    if(isset($_GET['min']) && isset($_GET['max']) && $_GET['min'] != '' && $_GET['max'] != ''){
    $sWhere = "AND FROM_UNIXTIME(cm.added, '%Y%m%d') BETWEEN '$_GET[min]' AND '$_GET[max]'";
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", "c.fullname AS cname, c.shortname AS short, m.name AS mname, cc.name AS catname, FROM_UNIXTIME(cm.added, '%Y - %M %D') AS dateadded, 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(cm.added, '%d %M - %Y') AS searchdateadded")."
        FROM mdl_course_modules cm 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_modules m  on cm.module=m.id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_course c  on cm.course=c.id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN mdl_course_categories cc  on c.category=cc.id
        WHERE c.category != 0 $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";


    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```